# How to apply one argument to Array{Function, 1} element-wise smartly in Julia?

Tags: julia, elementwise-operations

I understand Julia can apply element-wise argument to a function by f.(x)
in v0.6

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
f = x->3x
@assert f.(x) = [3, 6, 9]
```

Now, I define f as Array{Function, 1}.

```
f1(x) = 3x
f2(x) = 4x
f = [f1,  f2]
x = 2
@assert isa(f,  Array{Function,1}) == true
# f.(x) is unavailable
```

I want to apply arguments to element-wise function like above syntax, not using `map`, `[_f(x) for _f in f]`

Can someone be familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can broadcast the pipe operator (`|>`), e.g.

```
x .|> f
```

Comment: Yes, it's a nice illustration of how elegant Julia code can be.

Answer (score 3):

You have to take care how to define x and f, in some cases you will fail. Your first x applied on your last f will fail.

```
julia> 5 .|> [x->2x, x->7x]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 10
 35

julia> [2, 5] .|> [x->2x, x->7x]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
  4
 35

julia> [2 5] .|> [x->2x, x->7x]
2-element Array{Int64,2}:
  4  10
 14  35

julia> [2 5] .|> [x->2x x->7x]
1×2 Array{Int64,2}:
4  35

julia> [2, 5] .|> [x->2x x->7x]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  14
10  35

julia> [2 3 5] .|> [x->2x x->7x]
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common")

julia> [2, 3, 5] .|> [x->2x, x->7x]
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common")

julia> x = [1, 2, 3]; f = [x->2x, x->3x]; x .|> f
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common")
```

Comment: Did you mistake the second example from the last?

```size([2, 3, 5]) = (3, 1)
size([x->2x x->7x]) = (1, 2)
```
The size of the returning Array is (3, 2).
It can work correctly.

Comment: I rechecked broadcasting, tnanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it's great now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility:

```
((f, x)->f(x)).([f1, f2], x)
```